# Why does dividing these two Pandas series results in a series of NaN?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have two Pandas DataFrames, from which I would like to divide the first column of the first DataFrame by the first column of the second. These columns are minute-by-minute values, and I would like to divide one-hour intervals.

The first DataFrame is a bit larger than the second. I look for the indices in the first DataFrame that match up with the second, and then do my division. I then add 1 to the start and stop index of my first column, and divide again. I do this 30 times.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
keys = ['BX_GSE', 'BY_GSE', 'BZ_GSE', 'Vx', 'Vy', 'Vz', 'proton_density', 'T']
max_avg = []
timeshift_offset = []

for k in keys:
    averages_storage_array = []
    for n in range(30): # Calculate the ratios between points over a 30-minute window
        ratio_of_points = sliding[k][sliding_start-n:sliding_stop-n] / fixed[k [j:j+60])
        averaged_ratio_1hr = np.average(ratio_of_points)
        averages_storage_array.append(averaged_ratio_1hr)

    max_avg.append(max(averages_storage_array))
    timeshift_offset.append(averages_storage_array.index(max(averages_storage_array)))
```

Whenever I run this however, the entire `ratio_of_points` array is just filled with NaN values! The data that are loaded in are of type `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>` and the individual elements are of `<class 'numpy.float64'>` so they are not strings or something else weird. They are also all nonzero.

For example, printing the first 10 elements gives

```
print(sliding[k][sliding_start:sliding_start+10])
30   -1.284938
31   -1.219414
32   -0.936132
33   -0.801830
34   -0.848222
35   -1.291175
36   -1.470336
37   -1.428876
38   -1.318022
39   -1.303974
```

And the first 10 of the other input gives:

```
print(fixed[k][j:j+10])
0   -3.22
1   -3.58
2   -3.51
3   -1.62
4   -1.78
5   -1.40
6   -1.19
7   -1.50
8   -1.58
9   -1.09
```

Furthermore, not only does `/` do this, but so does `np.divide()` and `pandas.Series.divide'. The only thing that I could think of is that the DataFrame indices don't match up and it's causing an error. Is there any way to force divison between the two series *regardless of index*? My only thought would be to convert it into a regular/numpy series.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use loops to reindex and slice manually.

Take advantage of pandas index alignment and use [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) to shift your columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
out = df.div(df.shift(axis=1))
```

Output:

```
    0     1    2
0 NaN  2.00  1.5
1 NaN  1.25  1.2
```

If you want to avoid the `NaN` you can provide a fill value to [`div`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html):

```
out = df.div(df.shift(axis=1), fill_value=1)
```

Output:

```
     0     1    2
0  1.0  2.00  1.5
1  4.0  1.25  1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like when dividing two DataFrames, the index does matter and missing values at that index are filled with NaN. Because the two don't match up (the sliding one starts at 30) it thinks there are no values at those indices for the fixed one! One way to fix it could be to call `pandas.Series.to_numpy` to create Numpy arrays which you can divide.